# How can I pass a datetime property when creating nodes out of a list of records?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm evaluating Neo4j and Cypher to be used in production software, I'm migrating data from SQL server, but for this, I'm not using the LOADCSV cypher command since I need more control over the created nodes and relationships.
What I'm doing right now is similar to this:

```
{
  "props" : [ {
    "name" : "Andres",
    "position" : "Developer",
    "date": "2018-01-01"
  }, {
    "name" : "Michael",
    "position" : "Developer"
  } ]
}

UNWIND $props AS map
CREATE (n:Person)
SET n = map
```

and what I'm trying to achieve is to have the date property on the correct data type (datetime). Is there a way to tell Cypher to parse that field as a datetime?

NOTE: I've already tried the "SET n.Date = datetime(map.date)" approach but this adds the property Date also to the second record where I do not need it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that if the assignment value is NULL, then the property is not created or deleted:

```
WITH [ { name: "Andres",  position: "Developer", date: "2018-01-01" }, 
       { name: "Michael", position: "Developer" } ] AS props
UNWIND props AS map CREATE (n:Person) 
SET n = map, 
    n.date = CASE WHEN n.date IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE datetime(n.date) END
RETURN n
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use `datetime()` but this might need some change in your code.
General syntax:

```
CREATE (n:Person {name: toString("John"), age:toInteger(25), dob:datetime("2018-01-01")})
```